# How to find proper subsets of vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ that fulfill the following requirements?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How to find proper subsets $S_1, S_2, S_3$ (that are different from $\{(0,0)\}$ and $\varnothing$) of vector space  $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that
$S_1+S_1\subsetneq S_1,\\
S_2\subsetneq S_2+S_2,\\
S_3+S_3=S_3?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $S_1$: e.g. $S_1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x \in \mathbb{N}, y=0 \}$ (here $(1,0) \in S_1$ but $(1,0) \not \in S_1 + S_1$)

For $S_2$: e.g. the unit ball $B_1(0)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ |x| \leq 1 \}$

For $S_3$: e.g. a $1$-dimensional linear subspace

Comment: Yes. Consider the two vectors $a=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ and $b=(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$. They have length 1 and when you add them, you get the vector $(1,0)$. Obviously you can reach then every other point on the unit circle by rotating the vectors $a$ and $b$. Hence $S_2 \subset S_2 + S_2$. That $S_2 \not = S_2 + S_2$ is trivial.